# Protobuf model to c# model mapping

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

How can I map this proto model

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "GrpcFeedUpsert";

package feed;

service ActivityFeedUpsert {
  rpc Upsert(FeedUpsertRequest) returns (FeedUpsertResponse);
}

  message Users {
  uint32 Id = 1;
  string Name = 2;
  string Surname = 3;
}

message FeedUpsertRequest {
    uint32 Id = 1;
    uint32 UserId = 2;
    int32 Type = 3;
    string CreatedOnUtc = 4;
    repeated Users Users = 5;
}

message FeedUpsertResponse {
  string Id = 1;
}
```

to this C# model

using System.Runtime.Serialization;

```
namespace activity_feed_service.MongoDb
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    namespace activityFeed
    {
        [DataContract]
        public class Users
        {
            [DataMember(Order = 1)]
            public long Id { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Order = 2)]
            public string Name { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Order = 3)]
            public string Surname { get; set; }

        }

        [DataContract]
        public class ActivityFeed
        {
            [DataMember(Order = 1)]
            public long Id { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Order = 2)]
            public long UserId { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Order = 3)]
            public int Type { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Order = 4)]
            public string CreatedOnUtc { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Order = 5)]
            public List<Users> Users { get; set; }

        }
    }
}
```

I have a GRPC microservice that sends incoming data to mongoDB with a certain model. I could not manipulate the data coming from the GRPC model. There is a repeat field in the incoming data and I could not map this field to my model. How do I map these models above the models. ToList or Select functions do not work in the model from GRPC?

Comment: Repeated should map to list just fine. What specific issue are you seeing? To get an idea of alternatives, you could run the proto through the protobuf-net.BuildTools or https://protogen.marcgravell.com, but on a casual inspection that looks about right

Answer (score 0):

I used to AutoMapper and solve this issue like this:

```
  CreateMap<GrpcActivityFeed.ActivityFeed, activity_feed_service.Models.ActivityFeed.ActivityFeed>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Users, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Users))
```

Automatically mapped all repeated fields.

Comment: Please don't just recommend a library without any information about what the library is or how, specifically, it can be used to solve this specific problem. [Learn more](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251602/recommending-off-site-resources-when-questions-dont-ask-for-it/251605#251605).

Comment: At minimum, please [edit] your answer to include details on _how_ you used AutoMapper to map that specific proto model to that specific C# model. What did your configuration or code look like? Did you need to add any attributes to aid in the mapping? These are the types of details that will be useful for people in the future with a similar problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).